# Realm - How to build a feed with multiple types of objects?

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm trying to use Realm to build a feed for my app. I want the feed to include everything new: posts, comments, events, and other things I have in my app.

I have these all defined as POJOs that extend `RealmObject`, and they all have a `createdAt` property, however I can't find a way to query the whole Realm for objects sorted by their `createdAt`. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately realm does not support polymophism/inheritance in realm objects. You can easily loop through each data set and merge them together according to `createdAt`. Using [`DynamicRealm`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#dynamic-realms) this can be easily done.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I just had a single object for all types, when I needed to show all `FeedItem`s in the feed. And they had a `type` parameter that defined what they are.

Not exactly OOP and all, but it worked fine for my purposes. Simpler than using `DynamicRealm`.